# Invalid command interpolate in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to create a heat map out of a data file in gnuplot. I use 'set pm3d interpolate 0,0' but I get 'invalid command' for the interpolate part. Do you know what is the problem?thank you

Comment: Please post a sample data structure and a minimal example script that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which gnuplot version do you have? `set pm3d interpolate` is supported at least since version 4.2.0.

Comment: I use gnuplot 4.0 that is why the interpolate is not working. I downloaded the new version but it still does not produce the results I thought it would e.g (starkoverflow.com/questions/21663358/gnuplot-heatmap-xyz)

Comment: Then please give us a minimal example script, which shows us what you're doing and what is wrong.

Comment: I have a data file and I do : 
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
splot 'file.dat' and it gives the same result like the one when using just the splot command i.e. a 3D plot of my data.

Comment: If you want a heatmap, you must use `set pm3d map`. BTW: If you want to notify a specific user with a comment your write, you should use e.g. @Christoph so that he gets a notification about your comment.

Comment: @Christoph Thank you for your quick responses. This doesnt work either. Actually, I have downloaded the gnuplot for windows and i transfer my data file from the linux server where I work. I am trying to give you details probably irrelevant because I really can't see why this is not working. When i used the set pm3d map it returns a null image with the axis and stuff.

Comment: Its quite difficult to track down your problem. So `splot 'file'` (only this command!) works fine and shows you a gridded surface, but `set pm3d map; splot 'file'` doesn't work? Which output terminal do you use?

Comment: @Christoph Terminal type set to 'wxt', if that is what you mean. Thanx for your time!

Comment: Ok, just to make sure :) What about my other questions?

Comment: @ Christoph What other questions? When I write splot "file" I get the expected figure, when I use set pm3d map and then splot i get an empty figure. I actually want to visualize the advection diffsion equation in a heat map (like in the link I shared before from someone else's post) rather that in the 3d grid. I also said that I downoaled the gnuplot for windows but I transer a data file from a linux server(which I think is irrelevant). I do not know what else I could say because these are the exact steps I follow!:)

Comment: Yes, you are right :) Then I have no idea what might be wrong. Do you get any warning? What if you output to a file with e.g. `reset; set terminal postscript eps color; set output 'heatmap.eps'; set pm3d map; splot 'file'`?

Comment: Great :) What was the main problem in the end?